# What is this misterious entry on my FritzBox router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, fritzbox

My router at home is a FritzBox. When I go into the control panel and I look at the devices connected in the local network, and I see something very particular.

[image]

`mercury` is the name of my Desktop computer. For some reason it appears twice in the list. One appears with Internet connection and another one without it.

Can someone explain me why is this?

Comment: Do you have both a wired and wireless connection to this router?

Comment: No, the only device attached through cable to the router is a Synology Diskstation. You can see that it appears "LAN", not "WLAN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have the same model and firmware (I use a FB 7490 and Fritz!OS 6.30) and you didn’t show the complete device list.

Is it possible that you maybe use FRITZ "Powerline" adapters? I have only yet seen the blue arrow symbol on newer Fritz!Box firmwares since they now also support (and show) Powerline adapters.

I’d like to show you my list (as it looks on FRITZ!OS 6.30) but unfortunately I’m currently running a beta of what the firmware will look like in autumn 2015 …

[image: Fritz!Box 7490 "Heimnetzübersicht" as of Fritz!OS v06.36-31504 BETA]

This already shows the Powerline adapters in clear, not using the blue arrow symbols (as Fritz!OS 6.30 does).

Comment: Yes, I do use powerlines. That must be it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, great you’re still around! I realized too late that the question was very old—but posted it nevertheless as information for others.

Comment: Well, it was never a problem. Just something I wanted to understand :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You’re very welcome! Just something else that comes to mind: With newer Fritz!OS’es (like mine shown), it will even tell you if the powerline firmware is up-to-date and you can rename and/or update the Powerline units through Fritz!Box.

In the beginning, I also had the "problem" like you that I named my Powerlines a little odd so I always wondered. Now, as you can see, I simply prefix all of them with "pl-" and give them a sensible name like "pl-router", "pl-printer", "pl-livingroom", etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Network devices are listed twice in the list of "Devices and Users" if they automatically obtained their IP settings from the FRITZ!Box (DHCP client) once and on another occasion were connected to the FRITZ!Box with IP addresses that were manually assigned to them. This is not an error on the part of the FRITZ!Box.
>
> If these duplicate entries bother you, you can delete them...

Reference (couldn't find reference for your exact model but close enough I reckon):

http://tinyurl.com/ovo3gnd